# SharePoint alternatives for designing and executing processes

Tags: web-apps, project-management, collaboration, process-control, sharepoint

I'm looking for a collaborative web application used for designing and executing various project processes.

Suppose that tomorrow I had a requirement to build a tracking application for a project management organization, that dealt with specialized rules around travel requests.  Users should fill out a basic travel request form, with some basic validation.   We'd want a database of submissions, with the ability to build in certain simple rules, like notify this person when a record is submitted, filter records a certain way, perhaps do some simple calculations and display them on a dashboard.

We have been using SharePoint and designing custom lists with workflows, and have found it very painful due to the fact that SharePoint isn't a true database.  Regular project management software doesn't seem quite to be a fit; is there anything out there that will allow quick, GUI-based design of simple processes that capture, process, and report information?

Answer (score 1):

[Activiti](http://activiti.org/) is designed exactly for this.

It is a workflows engine, and is open source.
Unlike SharePoint, it is standards-compliant and well-documented.

First, create the workflow definition:

[image: Activiti workflow definition]

Then, use the worflow, either in your custom UI or with the built-in UI:

[image: Activiti user]

Should you need to check the database, it is not far away:

[image: Activiti database]

You can actually choose the underlying database. While any JDBC-compatible database should do, the following are officially supported:

- MySQL
- PostGre
- Oracle
- DB2
- MS SQL
- H2

[Getting started: 10 minutes tutorial](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_getting_started_10_minute_tutorial)